# Color DataGridView in Visual Studio

Tags: c#, winforms

I am looking to have alternating datagridview rows.

Like so:

[image]

Comment: WPF? WinForms? What framework are you using?

Answer (score 6):

You can arrange that in the `AlternatingRowsDefaultCellStyle` and `RowsDefaultCellStyle` property of your datagridview.

---

**Step 1**

Click on the button for your `DataGridViewCellStyle`

[image: AlternatingRowsDefaultCellStyle]

**Step 2**

Select the color for the alternating row

[image: Row back color]

---

Repeat for the RowsDefaultCellStyle to have different colors. By default both are set to a back color of white. Adjust as you wish.